# How can I insert a linebreak every 20 strings using ranges v3?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a vector of OpenCV points and want to print 20 of them per line.

The following code works, but I don't like that it needs to create intermediate vectors.

```
const std::vector<cv::Point> points { .... };

fmt::print("20 points per line:\n{}",
           points | ranges::views::transform([](const auto& point) {
                      return fmt::format("({}, {})", point.x, point.y);
                    }) 
                  | ranges::views::chunk(20)
                  | ranges::views::transform([](const auto& chunk) {
                      // really ugly
                      return chunk | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>;
                    })
                  // but how can I do this otherwise?
                  | ranges::views::intersperse(std::vector<std::string>{"\n"})
                  | ranges::views::join 
                  | ranges::views::join 
                  | ranges::to<std::string>);
```

Can I somehow intersperse a linebreak every 20 strings by directly specifying that this is supposed to be a range of the same type, or otherwise get around the intermediate `to<vector<string>>`?

What doesn't work, for reasons I don't understand, is just using

```
| ranges::views::intersperse(ranges::view::single(std::string{"\n"}))
```

directly after the chunk.

**[Run on CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3fx3Gnb4c)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use concat view instead.

https://godbolt.org/z/WYoqr1z9G

```
    std::string result = points 
        | ranges::views::transform([](auto&& point) {
            return fmt::format("({}, {})"sv, point.x, point.y);
        })
        | ranges::views::chunk(5)
        | ranges::views::transform([](auto&& chunk) {
            return ranges::views::concat(chunk | ranges::views::join, "\n"sv);
        })
        | ranges::views::join
        | ranges::to<std::string>;
```

**EDIT**

As in what I was mentioning in comment, is about C++23 implementation of interparse -- join_with; [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9dxo9coz9)

```
    auto result = points 
        | ranges::views::transform([](auto&& point) {
            return fmt::format("({}, {})"sv, point.x, point.y);
        })
        | ranges::views::chunk(5)
        | ranges::views::transform([](auto&& chunk) {
            return chunk | ranges::views::join | ranges::to<std::string>();
        })
        | ranges::views::join_with("\n"sv)
        | ranges::to<std::string>();
```

If someone knows how to flatten a chunk_view to string_view compatible without allocating additional string copies that is much appreciated.

Comment: personally I would be interested if someone knows how to do this in c++23 ranges without implementing my own concat. if I were to use join_with(line_break) i need to ensure typeof(line_break) is equivalent to the range element of the last transform call.